# git-svn: how to create a tag/branch for a sub project of SVN

Tags: git, svn, tags, branch

Base on the hit from answers below. I found the solution.

1. Clone SVN:
   `$ git svn clone http://foo.net/code/design --trunk=trunk/proj1 --tags=tags/forProj1 --branches=branches/forProj1 localProjName`
2. Then the tag can be created with simple command
   `$ git svn tag -n -m "test tag" test_v1`

Notes: That can also be done by hack .git/config in the local git clone by change it as

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
     url = http://foo.net/code/design
     fetch = trunk/proj1:refs/remotes/trunk
     tags = tags/forProj1/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
     branches = branches/forProj1/*:refs/remotes/branches/*
```

***Original Question*** 
My SVN server structure is like this:

```
http://foo.net/code/design/
                          |-- trunk/
                          |        |-- proj1
                          |        |-- proj2
                          |-- tags/
                          |       |-- forProj1
                          |       |-- forProj2
                          |-- branches/
                          |           |-- forProj1
```

I checkout the proj1:

`$ git svn clone http://foo.net/code/design/trunk/proj1 proj1`

and I want to create a tag for proj1 and put that tag under http://foo.net/code/design/tags/forproj1

I tried :

`$ git svn tag -m "test tag for proj1" test_tag_1`

I got error message said I have to put "--destination". But I don't know what the destination option should look like?

Can anyone give me a hint how could I create a tag or a branch base on above scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, use a `-n` switch for dry run, so you can ensure what the command does is the thing you want done. With SVN, otherwise, it can be a mess.

Next, your project layout is not the standard, so git wouldn't know where the tag for the project1 would go. In a standard layout, trunk and tags would be siblings, in that case you could have used a command like:

```
git svn tag "project1_v12" -m "Version 1.2"
```

Since SVN tag can execute at the server directly (even without an svn checkout), my approach to do this would be run the svn command directly, like so:

```
svn cp svn_url/trunk/proj1 svn_url/tags/forproj1/v1.2
```

and then a normal `git fetch` would have updated the tag v1.2 in the local git under the "svn" remote namespace.

Comment: I tried above command `git svn tag "project1_v12" -m "Version 1.2"`. But I got these error message: **Multiple tag paths defined for Subversion repository.
You must specify where you want to create the tag with the --destination argument.**

Comment: That is exactly what I was saying. It would be simple if the layout of your svn repo was understood by git, when you could execute this command. But since that doesn't happen, you should create a tag using the svn command mentioned above. Your git will be familiar with it's existence, once you do a fetch. Not that you don't need an svn checkout to run that, as you can execute it on the server directly.

Comment: @LakshmanPrasad does it mean that "git svn tag" command cannot be used in case like this ?

Answer (score -1):

Look at the values that you get when you do:

```
git config --get-all svn-remote.svn.tags
```

Once of these should match the tag location that you want.

Specify that for `--destination`

Comment: I tried you solution. There's no output for that command. So I still don't know what's the --destination option should be.